# Set question mark dot color? Possible?

Tags: css

I found this answer an other SO question and was wondering if the same thing is possible for question mark dots? Setting a certain color for the dot only.

jsbin.com/urOtixog/1/edit?html,css,output

Any ideas are welcome. 
Thanks for your time and thoughts guys!

BR

Comment: Please reject my edit review
Its a mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used your example code as a base here and did something similar. I used the `span` tag around the `?` and set the `:before` sudo-element to be a `.` that I overlayed on top of the question mark. You might have to adjust the `margin-left` to align with the font you're using.

```css
p {
  font-size: 65px;
}
.question {  
  color: black;
  position: relative;
}
.question:before {
  content: ".";
  position: absolute; 
  color: red;
  margin-left:5px
}
```

```html
<p>this<span class="question">?</span></p>
```